# Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'jsonfile' named JSON

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swifty-json

I currently have a button set to go to a TableViewController but decided I wanted to embed that TableViewController in a TabBarController. I am running into an error while trying to pass it to the UITabBarController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showListSegue") {
        let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0 // choose which tab is selected
        let des = tabBarController.selectedViewController!
        des.jsonfile = self.jsonfile
    }
}
```

In the last line of code,  `des.jsonfile = self.jsonfile`, I am getting the error...

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'jsonfile'

I am trying to pass the jsonfile to the TableViewController which is now embedded in the UITabBarController. How can this be done? I have this variable in the TableViewController is was getting passed to but now that I threw this TabBarController in the mix I am getting all confused.

I also tried to create a Cocoa file for the TabBarcontroller and set the variable `var jsonfile : JSON!` but that did not work either. (That is the variable in my TableViewController that I want to pass it to) Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You need to cast the `UIViewController` to your `TableViewController` and then access the `jsonfile` property from there.

Comment: Could I maybe see an example?

Comment: Just change the UITabBarController to the classname of your ViewController. Make sure it is built (cmd + b)

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the compiler know that `selectedViewController` is a type with the member `jsonFile`. Also, you should check that it actually is existing and of the correct class at runtime. Here's the kind of pattern you should be using:

```
class JSONDisplayController: UIViewController {
    var jsonfile: String
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showListSegue") {
        guard let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as? UITabBarController else {
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected destination.")
        }

        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0 // choose which tab is selected
        guard let des = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? JSONDisplayController else {
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected selection.")
        }

        des.jsonfile = jsonfile
    }
}
```